# Actions on Google Not waiting for answer when media is playing

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am working on a radio player for Google Home.  The app has multiple "stations" for listening to all setup as different intents with different url streams.  When a station is playing you can say "OK google"  and say the name of another intent(station), and it switches fine.  However, I have another intent ("List Stations") that gives you a list of stations, and then asks which station do you want.  If you have a station playing, and then ask "OK google, List Stations" the music stops, and after listing the stations the mic turns off and does not wait for a answer.  If you ask "OK google, List Stations" again, it will list the stations and the second time, the mic stays on waiting for a response like it should.  It only seems to not work if you had music playing when you ask for the list.

here is the intent code for listing the stations:

```
app.intent('stations', conv => {
        let responseToUser = {
            speech: "You can choose from Country, Christmas, or Gospel. Which station would you like?"
        };
        conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(responseToUser));
});
```

Comment: When you say "the mic turns off", do you get the closing chirp indicating it has exited the conversation?

Comment: No chirp, but the lights that indicate it is listening turn off, and it doesn't respond to voice command. Unless I start over with "OK Google"

Comment: And, just to confirm, you don't get any event that indicates the media status, correct?

Comment: (I've seen similar issues with Media Response and have reported it. I'm trying to get additional info for the team to address it.)

Comment: Correct, no media status events.  Also note, these are live streams (Which I've seen aren't supported yet, but they play fine) vs mp3 files. So that may be the real issue here.   I think I will swap one out for a mp3 file and see if I get the same results.

Comment: I tried with a .mp3 file url and had the same results.  Google Home did not wait for a response.